# loop through dirs and compare the dates to get the large one

Tags: php, function, loops, recursion

I already use this **function** in my question, so i need to use it again, but the question is different.
Here's the function:

```
public function loopThroughDirs($dir)
{      
  $timeMod = filectime($dir);
  $dateMod = ($timeMod) ? date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $timeMod) : ' - ';

if($handle = opendir($dir)){
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ( $entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            if(is_dir($dir.$entry)){
                $this->loopThroughDirs($dir.$entry.'/');
            } 
       }
    } 
    closedir($handle);
} 

var_dump($timeMod);

 }
```

so this is **recursive function** witch allow me to walk through **directories**, and when i

> var_dump()

the

> $timeMod

it shows me the time in secs of every folder.

*I need to check every folder with each other as the function loops so i can get the biggest $**timeMod** and place it in my **$defaultDate***,(put this inside the same function) something like this:

```
$defaultDate = 0;
if ($timeMod > $defaultDate){
$defaultDate = $timeMod;
}
```

So i try to insert this into my **function**, but every time when i invoke the **function**, it return me just the date (**$timeMod**) of my parent dir.
I need help to understand this, thanks.

Comment: You have to make `$defaultDate` variable static: `static $defaultDate = 0;`

Comment: ^ or pass it in to the function.  Another approach maybe: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1501522

Comment: @hindmost thanks :) that was the problem, my brain needs recharging :) cheers

Comment: @ficuscr, thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make `$defaultDate` variable static. Also you have to reset it to 0 at each external call of the function.
So the code should look like this:

```
public function loopThroughDirs($dir, $level = 0)
{
    static $defaultDate = 0;
    if (!$level) $defaultDate = 0;
    if ($timeMod > $defaultDate) $defaultDate = $timeMod;
    $timeMod = filectime($dir);
    $dateMod = ($timeMod) ? date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $timeMod) : ' - ';

    if ($handle = opendir($dir))
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ( $entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            if(is_dir($dir.$entry)){
                $this->loopThroughDirs($dir.$entry.'/', $level+1);
            } 
       }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    var_dump($timeMod);
    return $defaultDate;
}
```